# Finding the infinite sum of $e^{-n}$ using integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I am trying to understand this:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n}$ using integrals, what I have though:

$= \displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} e^{-n}$

$= \displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m} me^{-n}$

So, suppose this is an right-hand Riemann sum, with $m$ *Equal* subintervals.

$f(x_i) = me^{-n}$ represents the *height* of the function, we will have the integral for.

$\Delta(x) = \frac{1}{m}$

But, How can this be represented as an integral?

Thanks!

Comment: This sum can be computed exactly with a geometric series, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n = \frac{1/e}{1-(1/e)} = \frac{1}{e-1}$$

Comment: @Joel: OP probably knows this. He is trying to use a different method to arrive at the same result. This is an exercise in Riemann sums.

Comment: @MPW, thanks, exactly, I am trying to explore this integral method.

Comment: It's not meant to be an answer. That's why it's a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's not what you want, but it uses integral method...

We compute the integral $$\int_0^{e^{-1}}1 dx$$ using the partition $\{e^{-n}, n\geq 1\}$, since the integrand is constant we have

$$\int_0^{e^{-1}}1 dx = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(e^{-n} - e^{-(n+1)}\right)$$

i.e. $$e^{-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(e^{-n} - e^{-(n+1)}\right) = (1-e^{-1})\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-n}$$

so $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-n} = \dfrac{e^{-1}}{1-e^{-1}} = \frac{1}{e-1}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18338/discussion-on-answer-by-petite-etincelle-finding-the-infinite-sum-of-e-n-us).

Answer (score 2):

In the following I shall not convert the required sum into a Riemann sum, but use the  primitive $x\mapsto -e^{-x}$ of $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ to sum the series without "algebraic tricks". From
$$\int_n^{n+1}e^{-x}\>dx=-e^{-x}\biggr|_n^{n+1}=e^{-n}\left(1-{1\over e}\right)\qquad(n\geq1)$$
it follows that
$$\int_1^\infty e^{-x}\>dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}e^{-x}\>dx=\left(1-{1\over e}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}\ .$$
Solving for the sum in question we obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}={e\over e-1}\int_1^\infty e^{-x}\>dx={e\over e-1}\cdot {1\over e}={1\over e-1}\ .$$

Comment: thank you, but how did you get that integral? How do you get from Riemann Sum to integrals? Please take a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998713/finding-an-integral-for-a-given-riemann-sum?noredirect=1#comment2042098_998713

Where I ask this deeply, perhaps you can help? Thanks!

Comment: I really like this approach. It's a nontrivial connection between the sum and integration.