# How to represent exponential function as a some mathematical series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I want to implement the following function in the Matlab:

$Y = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{N} e^{(-i^n.B)}$

Where $n$ and $B$ are the constants.

When the value of $N$ is very very large, the equation takes a significant amount of computation time. Is there any way that I can represent this equation as some mathematical series, and then using formula for summation of the first $N$ terms of the series can quickly give the $Y$ as like in geometric series?

Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: for even values of n, you have an easy summation, for odd values of n, consider:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998286/finding-the-infinite-sum-of-e-n-using-integrals

Comment: This will converge *very* quickly, so why do you need to compute it for large $N$? Unless you are using arbitrary-precision arithmetic, the digits will quickly stabilize.

Comment: Assuming $B>0$ that is.  For $B<0$ this will become absurdly large.

Comment: I agree with Jair Taylor. **If N is very large**, then for any tolerance $t$ you can find $M<N$ such that: $$\sum_{i=M}^N e^{-B i^n} < t$$ so you can safely drop those terms and estimate your sum using $M$ first terms ($i=0,...,M-1$)

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I am using double-precision numbers. The value of $B<0$ and $n=2.5$. I am looking for a computationally quick method.

Comment: If B < 0, then you could quickly get overflow in double precision. Which means there's some $N_m$, the maximum number of terms you can possibly evaluate.

Comment: I can evaluate from $i=0$ to $i=10^8$. After that, the variables overflow. Even it takes on average 3-4 minutes for the computation. The range of $i=0$ to $i=10^8$ is enough for me but the computation time is an issue. Kindly help.

Comment: If $n=2$, $B = 1$, and $i = 10^8$, $e^{-Bi^n}$ is on the order of .00000...1 where the number of zeroes before the one on the order of 10^16 / ln(10) or ~ 1 trillion.  That's the *number of zeroes*, not the number.  So you're computing the sum to an accuracy of ~ 1 trillion digits.  Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Excuse me, quadrillion, not trillion...